# Regarding the NCBI FTP site

Tags: bioinformatics, snp

I am trying to extract information about SNP data from the FTP server of NCBI. Could someone please explain to me how the directory is organised? There are many many files and folders and I can't figure which contains what. Is there one file which explains the organisation of the ftp site properly? The NCBI help manual did not give much help beyond helping me find species of interest.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK44376/) the help that your talking about? It is perfectly clear. What can you not figure out?

Comment: just a thought - its better to use biopython or some other script library to get what you want, especially if you are trying to get more than one item.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting SNP data from FTP Site of NCBI SNP:

It's actually simple to download the data from the NCBI, if you follow the method given by [FAQ](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK44376/)( as given by @WYSIWYG).

**Step 1:**

Goto organism FTP: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/organisms/

[image]

**Step 2**

Open your required organism folder:

[image]

---

From here you can download any file you wanted. If you trying to study the whole organism please download any one of the whole folders(ASN.1, rs_fasta, XML(recommended)).

Now,

It's not about the downloading it's about understanding the files which are provided.

files types:

- [XML files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)
- [ASN.1 or Abstract Syntax Notation One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)
- rs_fasta

All of them contents almost the same data, just in different format. It's up to you how your script(preferably Python or Perl) works to get out the import information.

---

[Other way of Download from NCBI FTP](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/books/NBK56563/):

You can always use filezilla:

[image]

- Put Host as : ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/organisms/
- rest Username and Password, etc empty